# Setting up Recaptcha problems

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha, contacts

I really need to get this finished today, it's driving me mad.  I have followed all the instructions for the Google Recaptcha.  However, I have not had any success in amending the original php file to include validating the recaptcha and then sending the information via email.

Can anyone give me an insight as to how to make this work and it's the last piece of the jigsaw!

Many thanks in advance...

```
<?php
        $msg1 = ''; $succeeded = ''; $failed = ''; $dest = ''; $sender = ''; $enqs = '';
// sort the POST array
ksort($_POST);
// iterate through the POST data and assign them to the email message or variables
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'formfail')
    $failed = $value;
    else if ($key == 'formsucc')
    $succeeded = $value;
    else if ($key == 'formdest')
    $dest = $value;
    // add the enquiry types for the subject header
    else if (substr($key,0,3) == 'cb_')
    if (strlen($enqs))
    $enqs .= ', ' . $value;
    else
    $enqs = $value;
    else
    $msg1 .= "$key: $value\n";
    if ($key == 'email')
    $sender = $value;
}
ini_set("sendmail_from", $dest);
$headers  = "From: $dest\r\n";
// send the email
    $sent = mail($dest, "Quote Request From Website: $enqs", $msg1, $headers, '-f' . $dest);
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please go back and check the  captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
        $secretKey = "*********************************************";
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
        $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
        header('Location: thankyou.htm');
exit();
        }
?>
```

Comment: show ur code...

Comment: @MuthuKumaran I have added it to the original post :)
I've inherited the original php file so I've been trying to amend it.  So far the captcha code works but the information from the contact form is not being emailed to the client.